# Angular 13 Cannot find module '@angular/common/locales

Tags: locale, angular13

I am updating to Angular 13 and I am seeing errors surrounding this import:

```
import(`@angular/common/locales/${lang.split('-')[0]}.js`).then(locale => {
registerLocaleData(locale.default); });
```

What should I be using?

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I have migrated to Angular 13. I also faced the same issue. The changes below worked for me.

```
import(`@/../@angular/common/locales/${lang}.mjs`)
.then(localModule => {
          registerLocaleData(localModule.default)
     });
```

Comment: Do you know the page where this change is mentioned as a part of Angular 13 migration? Your answer is the only place on Internet I could find mentioning @/../@angular... obsoleting /node_modules/@angular...